# How to solve Rails error: Image not found - ../digest/md5.bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

It probably has something to do with openssl. I'm on LibreSSL 2.8.3. Could this be causing the issues?

Anyway, any rails commands I use, like rails -v or rails new, throw me these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
23: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
22: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/bin/rails:23:in `load'
21: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
20: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
19: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
18: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
17: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
16: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:70:in `find_by_namespace'
15: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `lookup'
14: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:39:in `each'
13: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `block in lookup'
12: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:40:in `each'
11: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
10: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 9: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 8: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 7: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 6: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 5: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
 4: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 3: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
 2: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.2/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 1: from /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
```

/Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19/digest/md5.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19/digest/md5.bundle
Reason: image not found - /Users/Laurens/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19/digest/md5.bundle

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the ruby with rbenv `rbenv install 2.6.0`, because libssl 1.0.0. has been removed from your system, your current installation would not work.

Comment: I just tried that. Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. Is there any way to manually make it point to a different version of libssl? Sorry I am fairly new to all this. its telling me i have LibreSSL 2.8.3 installed.

Comment: Solved after reinstalling Rails gem.